# jQuery widgets, not how I thought they were?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I thought jQuery widgets were jQuery objects that were handily linked to DOM objects (so you could store state, for example, or handle events), but I'm having some problem with understanding the instance model here. I have an object as such ;

```
var xs_widgets = {

    jQuery : $,

    options: { },

    _create: function () {
        this.make_sortable() ;
    },

    _init: function () { alert ( 'init' ) ; }

    make_sortable: function () { alert ( 'make-sortable' ) ; }
}
```

I bind it to jQuery with ;

```
jQuery.widget( "ui.xs_widgets", xs_widgets );
```

And then, I try to bind some DOM elements to the widget ;

```
$('li.widget').xs_widgets();
```

Now here's the thing. I *thought* that each `<li class="widget">` got a jQuery object attached, but from what I can gather there's a global xs_widget object regardless, and it gets fed the jQuery objects from the query above, and you yourself have to deal with instance data? I thought the whole point of the widgets was to avoid the overhead of dealing with instances? The above code run against HTML that contains, say, two `<li>` elements yields ;

```
make-sortable
init
make-sortable
init
```

I was expecting ;

```
make-sortable
init
init
```

Oh, please help! I'm reading tutorials and articles, but I seem to be missing something vital somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your xs_widgets function widget gets called once for each matching element in your selector (so, twice with two  tags).

> I thought that each  got a jQuery object attached.

They do. Which is why _create and _init are both called twice. However, the create method will only be called once when adding the widget to the element. If you call `$('li.widget').xs_widgets();` again right after your first call, you'll only get:

> init
>   init

[Here's an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9NKUp/1/)

Comment: Thanks, yeah, after some more testing it seems that I got confused with how anonymous functions work inside these classes. One would think there was a mechanism for keeping a reference to the self widget object in the anonymous functions so that events can work properly? It seems I need to make queries inside them to get a good reference? Or is there some other magic I've missed?